# split array with delimiter into string

Tags: javascript

I have an `array` like below

```
["abc", "stued(!)rain(!)shane", "cricket"]
```

How can i convert this to `string` by spliting on `(#)` like below:

```
"abc"
"stued"
"rain"
"shane"
"cricket"
```

Below is the code i have tried

```
var arr = ["abc", "stued(!)rain(!)shane", "cricket"];
console.log(arr.join('').split("(!)"));
```

I am getting `abcstued,rain,shanecricket` which is not the desired `output`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `join` with the same delimiters.

```js
var arr = ["abc", "stued(!)rain(!)shane", "cricket"];
alert(arr.join('(!)').split("(!)"));
```

Answer (score 2):

This is missing, a solution with Array#reduce:

```js
var arr = ["abc", "stued(!)rain(!)shane", "cricket"],
    result = arr.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r.concat(a.split('(!)'));
    }, []);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: What is 0, 4 there in JSON.Stringify()

Comment: that is the replace and the spaces --> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 1):

```
var arrFinal = [];

arr.forEach(function(val, key) {
        arrFinal = arrFinal.concat(val.split('(!)'))
    })


console.log(arrFinal)
```